# What summation rule am I missing here?

Tags: linear-algebra, summation, solution-verification, alternative-proof, summation-method

I was trying to prove the associativity of matrix dot products and I think I almost got it till the last step where I'm stuck, probably due to my lack of knowledge about summation rules.

I have $A\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}, B\in\mathbb R^{n\times p}, C\in\mathbb R^{p\times q}$. And, I need to prove that $(AB)C =  A(BC).$

I've also taken general terms of $A,B$ and $C$ to be $a_{ih}$, $b_{hj}$ and $c_{jk}$ where
$i = 1,2,....m$
$h = 1,2,....n$
$j = 1,2,....p$
$k = 1,2,....q$

With all this I've found that:

1. General term of $(AB)C = \sum_{r=1}^{p}[\sum_{l=1}^{n}a_{il}b_{lr}c_{rk}]$
2. General term of $A(BC) = \sum_{l=1}^{n}[\sum_{r=1}^{p}a_{il}b_{lr}c_{rk}]$

Now, I know that the above two equations should be equal, but I'm not sure if there's a rule/property of summations that lets me exchange the places of the 2 summations so that I can equate the general terms.

So, bearing with me if I'm being too much of a noob, could somebody tell me if such a rule exists or if not what I can do instead?

*Note: Feel free to correct me if you think my whole proof is a mistake.*

Comment: This should just go through by the commutative and associative properties of addition, in both cases you're just summing up all of the elements of $\{a_{il}b_{lr}c_{rk} : 1 < l < n \bigwedge 1 < r < p\}.$ And it's a finite sum so you can change the order of addition without restrictions, so I see no problem with that.

Comment: Wow! Thanks @StephenDonovan, you may have just saved me a lot of time. Thanks for correcting my math formatting too.

Comment: No problem, have a good one

Comment: Alternatively you can use that function composition is associative and that multiplication by a matrix is a function.

Comment: You probably want to say matrix products or products of matrices and avoid "dot products" in relation to matrices, as this could lead to confusion. @CyclotomicField suggests a method which sometimes gets overlooked - of using the perspective of the vector space as a whole, and the functions on it, without choosing a basis. Just note: to do this you would have to have in your toolkit, or prove, that the matrix multiplication rule is equivalent to composition of functions, and also that every matrix arises from an appropriate function. But these are not difficult.

Comment: Thanks, @MarkBennet, I'll make sure to keep these things in mind.

Comment: Thanks to @CyclotomicField too